# How to replace all data that was entered (form) before with new data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic input section in my form that enters data into MySQL database
when the user enter data the first time it goes but when the user enters the second time it multiples the same data and enters the new data

I recommend paste this into you code editor and run it from there

HTML:

```
<form>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label for="inputFormRowskill" class="top_skills label">Top 6 Skills</label><br>
<?php
$get_skills_query = "SELECT * FROM users_skills WHERE `user_id` = ?;"; // query the database
$get_skills = $conn->prepare($get_skills_query); // prepare the query
$get_skills->bind_param("s", $user_id); //insert email
$get_skills->execute(); //execute the statment
$result_get_skills = $get_skills->get_result(); // get result
$num_skills_rows = $result_get_skills->num_rows;
                    
while($row_get_skills = $result_get_skills->fetch_assoc()){ // get result assoc
?>
<div id="inputFormRowskill">
<div class="input-group mb-3">
<input style="width:60%" type="text" name="skill[]" class=" input m-input" value="<?php echo $row_get_skills['skill']; ?>" autocomplete="on">
<div class="input-group-append">      
<a href="edit_public_profile.php?del=<?php echo $row_get_skills['id']; ?>" id="removeRowskill" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div id="newRowskill"></div> <!-- this is where the other rows will be added -->
<button id="addRowskill" type="button" class="btn">Add Skill</button>

<button name="saveinfo">save info</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript to make a new input:

```
var limit_skill = 5; // limit fields
var counter_skill = <?php echo $num_skills_rows; ?>; //field counter //get num_rows from MYSQL

        $("#addRowskill").click(function () {// add row
            var html = '';
            html += '<div id="inputFormRowskill">';
            html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
            html += '<input style="width:60%" type="text" name="skill[]" class="input m-input" placeholder="skill" autocomplete="off">';
            html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
            html += '<button id="removeRowskill" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            
            if(counter_skill <= limit_skill){
                counter_skill++;
                $('#newRowskill').append(html);
            } 
        });
        // remove row skill
        $(document).on('click', '#removeRowskill', function () {
            $(this).closest('#inputFormRowskill').remove();
            counter_skill--
        });
```

PHP when form is submited:

```
if(isset('saveinfo')){

$skill = $_POST['skill'];
foreach($skill as $skill){
$insert_into_db = $conn-> prepare("INSERT INTO users_skills(`user_id`,`skill`) VALUES(?,?)"); //query
$insert_into_db -> bind_param("ss", $user_id, $skill); // bind_param
$insert_into_db -> execute(); // execute
$insert_into_db -> store_result(); // store results
}
}
```

my db layout:

```
ID | user_id | skill
1  | 1242d   | something
```

Comment: You need to delete the old data and insert new, or  update the same row in the database

Comment: See INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY